# How to move a parent container's horizontal scroll position towards one of it's children elements nearest center?

Tags: javascript, css

Ok, so imagine I have a very simple scenario here. A container `<div>` that has a CSS property of `overflow-x: scroll`, it is 500px wide (visible width without the overflow) and it has 9 children. Children 1 to 4 and 6 to 9 have width of 100px, and number 5 (center one) has a width of 200px for a total of 1200px (total scroll width).

```html
<nav class="scrollable">
  <div style="width: 100px;">1</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">2</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">3</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">4</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">5</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">6</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">7</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">8</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">9</div>
</nav>
```

```css
.scrollable {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.scrollable > div {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

So far so good. So now the goal is whenever we click on one of these child `<div>`s (1 to 9), the scroll position of the parent element to move itself as close as possible towards the child that is being clicked, as I attempted to illustrate below. The child in lightblue color is the one that is currently selected:

[image: Scrollbar container and it's children]

As you can see, the scroll remains the same for elements 1-3 and 7-9, it shifts left and right for 4 and 6 and it goes to the absolute center for child number 5.

We can control the parent element's scroll position via the `parent.scrollLeft` property. In addition to that, we can get it's visible width or total with (including the overflow) with `parent.clientWidth` and `parent.scrollWidth` respectively.

In addition to that, each child element has it's own visible width, and `.offsetLeft` properly, which tells us how far from the parent's element left corner it is positioned.

With all that information in hand, I almost managed to achieve the original goal I have in mind.

```js
// event handler for the inner tabs

document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.closest('.scrollable > div')) {
    // the parent <div>
    const parent = event.target.closest('.scrollable');
    // the selected/clicked <div>
    const selected = event.target.closest('.scrollable > div'); 
    
    // center the parent's scrollbar around the selected/clicked child
    parent.scrollLeft = selected.offsetLeft - (selected.offsetWidth * 2);
  }
});
```

[Codepen example (working).](https://codepen.io/decho/pen/OJpwwoL)

The only problem here though, is that this calculation only works if all of the elements have the same width. But as soon as I change the width of a single element, then the scrollbar is no longer aligning properly. As shown in the example below, the width of child number 5 is 200px, while the rest remain 100px:

[Codepen example which illustrates the problem (not working).](https://codepen.io/decho/pen/BaWPOzz)

So obviously `const selected = event.target.closest('.scrollable > div');` is not the right formula I need to use here, but after spending hours on this and multiple variations, I can not figure out the right one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

---

**Solution:**

Okay, I must admit this went way over my head, but after a ton of brain-storming and trial end error, here is what it needs to be done in the odd chance someone stumbles upon the same problem in the future.

- First you get the `parent.clientWidth`, that is the visible area of the `scrollable` container (without the overflow), then subtract the clicked element's own width (`.offsetWidth`) from it.
- Divide that value by two.
- Finally, set the `parent.scrollLeft` to be equal to the clicked child's `.offsetLeft` and subtract the previous value we calculated from it.

```js
const remainingSpace = parent.clientWidth - target.offsetWidth;
const spaceLeftAndRight = remainingSpace / 2;
parent.scrollLeft = target.offsetLeft - spaceLeftAndRight;
```

**EDIT late 2022:**

In case the scrolling is not working as you expecting it to and it's not centering properly, make sure that the parent container (`scrollable`) has `position` set to `relative`. Otherwise the `offsetLeft` property of each child `<div>` will take the whole viewport into account when measuring, instead of of just it's parent (`scrollable`).

Comment: So, basically what you require is that independent of the widths of childs, the scroll should always be in the middle except the cases of corner elements, right ?

Comment: Well, not exactly. For example, in the screenshot demo I provided look at where it is positioned for elements #4 and #6. It is centered around them, but it's not the absolute center of the whole horizontal scrollbar. So slightly to the left and right relative to the center.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, the element is on the centre of the screen, but not on the centre of the wrapper element. Right ?

Comment: The elements from #3 to #7 are in the center of the screen and the wrapper (container), while the scroll is slightly left, center and slightly right. And for #1, 2 and #8, #9 it is not at the center of the wrapper or the screen because it has nowhere to go. You can check the 1st codepen link demo I provided, in there it works exactly as I want it to, except it breaks when you add a child <div> with different width than the rest.

Comment: @decho, did you find the solution ?

Comment: @mss, yes, the solution is at the bottom of my own question/post itself. Perhaps you missed it.

Comment: @decho, I missed it(as usually no one writes answer in the question ^_^), I think you should add your own answer to the question for future readers :)

Comment: Agreed with @mss, you should just copy that comment as an answer and mark as solved.

Helped me, thanks @decho!